# Unix command to generate four digit random number with four decimals

Tags: bash, unix

I want to generate a random number between 1000 and 9999 with 4 digit decimals.

eg : 2345.5678

For generating  a random four digit number i'm using the following

```
$((1000 + RANDOM % 9999))
```

How do i add decimal to this ?

Comment: `1000 + RANDOM % 9999` will produce a random integer between 1000 and 10998, inclusive. You want `1000 + RANDOM % 9000`

Answer (score 5):

You can use pretty much the same logic and just construct the number.

```
echo "$((1000 + RANDOM % 9999)).$((RANDOM % 9999))"
```

Comment: That will never generate 1234.0567 (1234.567 is not the same.) Use printf to output the appropriate number of leading zeros (`%4d.%04d`, for example). And see my comment about the arithmetic.